# how to prevent people accessing the Google form from copying and pasting the data into word?

Tags: javascript, google-forms

I have designed Google form for taking consent. I want to safeguard my Text matter and content in form and want to prevent my competitors to copy the form data.

Comment: You can't. If you can read it, you can copy it.

Comment: I am able to do same in normal HTML page .

Comment: This is an illusion. The click may be disabled. But I can always press [F12] and get the HTML code

Comment: I agree but at least some level of security will be there with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for html

```
<div
  class="form"
  oncopy="return false"
  oncut="return false"
  onpaste="return false"
></div>
```

or with DOM:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
form.oncopy = () => false;
form.oncut = () => false;
form.onpaste = () => false;
```

But it's experimental. And not every browser supports this.

Also you can try this CSS prop:

```css
.form {
  user-select: none:
}
```

Comment: I tried it didn't work. however I have java script code which disable click and screen selection when I embed in .html page and check. But I am not able to use same in my google form / script.